# Which operation cannot be performed after the request has been submitted?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse, compact-framework2.0

I'm successfully passing data between a handheld device (Compacted Framework/Windows CE) and a modern (not "modern" as in Windows 8, but as in 21st Century) server app (Web API). However, after the (successful) passing of data, the client fails with the err msg, "*This operation cannot be performed after the request has been submitted*"

Which operation is it complaining about? Here's my client code:

```
public static HttpWebResponse SendXMLFile(string xmlFilepath, string uri) 
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(xmlFilepath))
    {
        String line;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(line);
        }
    }

    string strData = @sb.ToString(); 
    strData = strData.Replace("\"", "'"); 
    string body = String.Format("\"{0}\"", strData);
    HttpWebRequest request = CreateRequestNoCredentials(uri, HttpMethods.POST, body, "application/json"); 

    MessageBox.Show("Made it past the call to CreateRequestNoCredentials()");
    try
    {
        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("ReadResponse val = {0}", RESTfulMethods.ReadResponse(response)));
            return response;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Msg = {0}; StackTrace = {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace));
        request.Abort();
        return null;
    }
}

public static HttpWebRequest CreateRequestNoCredentials(string uri, HttpMethods method, string data, string contentType)
{
    //test:
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("In CreateRequestNoCredentials(); data passed in = {0}", data));

    WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.Method = Enum.ToObject(typeof(HttpMethods), method).ToString();
    request.ContentType = contentType;
    ((HttpWebRequest)request).Accept = contentType;
    ((HttpWebRequest)request).KeepAlive = false;
    ((HttpWebRequest)request).ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;

    if (method != HttpMethods.GET && method != HttpMethods.DELETE)
    {
        Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        request.ContentLength = encoding.GetByteCount(data);
        request.GetRequestStream().Write(
          encoding.GetBytes(data), 0, (int)request.ContentLength);
        request.GetRequestStream().Close();
    }
    else
    {
        // If we're doing a GET or DELETE don't bother with this 
        request.ContentLength = 0;
    }
    // Finally, return the newly created request to the caller. 
    return request as HttpWebRequest;
}
```

It may be that the code following:

```
MessageBox.Show("Made it past the call to CreateRequestNoCredentials()");
```

...is unnecessary, but I'm apparently not even getting there, as I never see that message; I just see the aforementioned error, and then "*Error An unexpected error has occurred in Bla.exe Select Quite and then restart this program, or select Details for more information.*"

Details are: "*Error Bla.exe ObjectDisposedException at System.Threading.WaitHandle.CheckResultInternal(Boolean r) at...(etc.)*"

And then, "*Application Bla.exe encountered a serious error and must shut down.*"

So what's the trip-up?

### UPDATE

I don't understand the leadthumb response to this question.

An additional odd thing about it all is that, even though I get "encountered a serious error" it doesn't really seem to be as serious as other times the handheld app crashes, in which case I have to often warmboot the device and/or reseat the device in its cradle prior to copying a new version of the .exe over the old. But that is not happening with this "serious" error.

I simplified the code so that it no longer returns a HttpWebResponse, but I still get the same result. YET, what I want to happen works fine: the data is sent to the server app, and it successfully recreates an XML file from the data passed, and then updates a database by inserting a new record based on values passed.

Here's the new, streamlined code:

```
public static void SendXMLFile(string xmlFilepath, string uri, int timeout) // timeout should be 500
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(xmlFilepath))
    {
        String line;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(line);
        }
    }

    string strData = @sb.ToString();
    strData = strData.Replace("\"", "'");
    string body = String.Format("\"{0}\"", strData);
    CreateRequestNoCredentials(uri, HttpMethods.POST, body, "application/json"); 
}
```

### UPDATE 2

If I catch and ignore the exception this way:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (ex.Message.Contains("This operation cannot be performed after the request has been submitted"))
    {
        // just make like Johnny Bench
    }
}
```

...I can run the method without incident; however, when I then close the app, I get the "an unexpected error has occurred in Bla.exe. Select Quit and then restart this program, or select Details for more information."

### UPDATE 3

The suggested replacement code gives me, "*Cannot implicitly convert type 'byte[]' to 'long'*"

Changing it to this:

```
request.ContentLength = arrData;
```

...gives me, "*Cannot convert type 'byte[]' to 'long'*"

So it can't be either im- or explicitly converted to long...then...???

### UPDATE 4

Okay, arrData.Length works.

Comment: Somebody must have found that I used to have a "No Disco" t-shirt; or maybe it was the "No Golf" t-shirt...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run your code under the debugger and watch which line it fails on.

`GetRequestStream` should not be called more than once. You should consider changing your code to this:

```
byte[] arrData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
request.ContentLength = arrData.Length;
using (Stream oS = request.GetRequestStream()) 
{
     oS.Write(arrData, 0, arrData.Length);
}
```

Comment: I can't step through this code - it runs on a handheld device, with no emulator available.

Comment: This code isn't magical; you can run it in .NET 4.5 on Windows 8.1 if you want.

Comment: Please see update 3...never mind, arrData.Length works.