# Is Nullification Advisable?

Tags: c#, null, nullable, idisposable, generic-list

I don't mean to start a[nother] civil war over this issue, but should nullification be enforced or not?

While trying to fix a bug (that was fixed elsewise, as can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22490251/which-operation-cannot-be-performed-after-the-request-has-been-submitted/22492489)), I added code like this in a couple of places to immediately and explicitly set some objects to null:

```
List<String> XMLFiles = CCRUtils.GetXMLFiles(fileType, @"\");
foreach (string fullXMLFilePath in XMLFiles)
{
    RESTfulMethods.SendXMLFile(fullXMLFilePath, uri, 500);
}
XMLFiles = null;
```

Now that I know that did not solve the problem I was having, should I just leave it, or remove this type of code?

Comment: Remove it, it's pointless. The garbage collector will do that anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> should nullification be enforced or not?

In general, it should not.  There are very few circumstances where there is a reason to set a variable to null.  As soon as the scope in which the variable is declared ends, the reference to the object will no longer be held.

Setting a variable to `null` after use is (almost) always just a misunderstanding of how the GC works, and serves no purpose.